# Is Java Advanced Imaging lib still needed for deficiencies in Java ImageIO lIb

Tags: java, javax.imageio, jai

Is Java Advanced Imaging lib still needed for deficienies in Java ImageIO lib ?

In my code written a few years ago I have code such as:

```
BufferedImage b = null;
try {
    b = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
} catch (final CMMException ce) {
    if (path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
        b = loadImageFromFileUsingJAI(imagePath);
    }
}
// #3034:Jpeg Error
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aibe) {
    if (path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") || path.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
        b = loadImageFromFileUsingJAI(imagePath);
    }
}
```

i.e use JAI if ImageIO fails, but this was written when using Java 6, I'm now on Java 8 and likely to move to Java 9 soon, so I wonder of the JavaIO images have now been resolved?

Comment: I very much doubt that these issues have been resolved (and I doubt they ever will). That is one of the reasons I address issues such as these in my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) library. If you have sample files, I can test, but without that, it's impossible to know if it will fix exactly the problems you see.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information should be found in the Java SE release notes (off-site resource). Also, there's not enough information in the question to test whether this is resolved or if there are better solutions available (not verifiable).

Comment: @haraldK Ok, I actually used your Twelve Monkeys lib for PICT images, but dont anymore since it was supported in JavaIO, but if you are saying TwelveMonkeys still better supports JPeg than ImageIO I may revisit it. So could you tell me does it fix things that still don't work with ImageIO in Java 9.

Comment: Cool. Yes, TwelveMonkeys ImageIO supports many features not in the JRE (and still not there in Java 9), like CMYK JPEG, Lossless JPEG, broken ICC profiles and more. Whether or not it fixes the problems you experienced, I can't tell (as mentioned above).